# Bounding rectangle of a line

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

[Input]: the begin and end points of an arbitrary line (small red points) and the line width (green line)

[Example]: begin=(20,20), end=(100,50), width=5

[image]

[Output]: The set of pixels (not the total area) that are in the yellow rectangle

[Example]: {(20,20), (20,21), (20,22),...etc.}

How can i calculate the output set?

Comment: I think this still classifies as cross-posting. But, to me, it seems to be slightly worse since one has to click on the link before getting to the question.

Comment: i removed the question from stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

An algorithm to know if a point $P$ is in the rectangle $ABCD$ is to check that

- $\vec{AB}\cdot \vec{AP}\leq 0$,
- $\vec{DC}\cdot \vec{DP}\geq 0$,
- $\vec{DA}\cdot \vec{DP}\leq 0$, and
- $\vec{CB}\cdot \vec{CP}\geq 0$.

Since you have the two extremity point and the width $A,B,C$ and $D$ should be easy to compute. And you can restrict the point you are checking to $(x,y)$ such that $min(A_x,B_x,C_x,D_x)\leq x \leq max(A_x,B_x,C_x,D_x)$ and $min(A_y,B_y,C_y,D_y)\leq y \leq max(A_y,B_y,C_y,D_y)$.

It may not be optimal but it should be working.

Ps: I agree with @Dukeling.

**[Edit]** to compute $A$

If begin and end have the same abscissa (or ordinate) then it easy. Otherwise:

Let $begin=(b_x,b_y)$, $end=(e_x,e_y)$, $A=(x,y)$ and $width/2=w$ you know that:
$$\vec{beginend}=((e_x-b_x),(e_y-b_y))$$
$$\vec{beginA}=((x-b_x),(y-b_y))$$
hence:
$$\vec{beginend}\cdot\vec{beginA}=(e_x-b_x)(x-b_x)+(e_y-b_y)(y-b_y)=0$$
hence:
$$ x = b_x -\frac{(e_y-b_y)(y-b_y)}{(e_x-b_x)} $$
Also $|\vec{beginA}|=w$ hence:
$$(x-b_x)^2+(y-b_y)^2=w$$
hence:
$$(b_x -\frac{(e_y-b_y)(y-b_y)}{(e_x-b_x)}-b_x)^2+(y-b_y)^2=w$$
Solve this equation and you have $y$, then replace the solution in $$ x = b_x -\frac{(e_y-b_y)(y-b_y)}{(e_x-b_x)} $$ and you have $x$.

Notice that you have two solution one for $A$ the other for $D$ ...

Do the same for $B$ and $C$ with appropriate vectors.

Comment: The problem is that the line is random. Therefore i don't know how to compute the A,B,C,D of the rectangle

Comment: what do you mean the line is random? you are given 'begin' 'end' and the width right? so you can compute ABCD, no?

Comment: The user draws an arbitrary line. Let's imagine 3 different lines are sketched: one is verticel the other one is horizontal and the last one is with any unknown slope. How can you compute A,B,C,D in this case?

Comment: you have begin and end and width??

Comment: How the line (and its corresponding rectangle) is shaped, is based on the slope and (in my case) the Bresenham's Algorithm. You don't have any fixed line where you can say, i would just add the width to x or y coordinates of begin and end to find A,B,C,D.

Comment: Well you know that $\vec{BeginEnd}\cdot\vec{BeginA}=0$ and $|\vec{BeginA}|=\frac{width}{2}$ it should be enough no?

Comment: end the same for $B,C$ and $D$

Comment: if i don't know what A is, then how can i compute the vector BeginA, besides A is exactly what i'm looking for. Am i missing something?

Comment: A is indeed unknow and have two parameters, but miracle you have two independent equation to fix those parameters it's enough. See my edit.